# base url is getting calling an inner folder

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

When I use `echo base_url()` in some portions of the application, it works fine.

My `base_url()` is `http://localhost:8080/appname/`

But when I do this `<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/profile/avatar-5.png`

The url appears like http://localhost:8080/appname/admin/data/profile/avatar-5.png where admin is a folder.  I guess its because from where it is called from.  But yet the base_url() should actually give the right url.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should share some code. Anyway, have you assign the correct URL to `$config['base_url']` in **config.php**?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `base_url()`, you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in `application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, manually:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Also don't forget to set `base_url` in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost:8080/appname/';
```

Then try

```
<?php echo base_url('data/profile/avatar-5.png'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the base path is not working for you, you can try my solution which I usually use

Create an separate path for logo or image

```
$config['image_path'] = ' http://localhost:8080/appname/admin/data/profile/';
```

use that in you view controller as

```
echo $this->config->item('image_path').$imagename;
```